# processing: button press switch state

Tags: button, state, processing

So I have a ON-OFF button that draws a circle. The trouble I am encountering is that the ON OFF states are random depending on how long I press the button. I guess this is due to the draw() function which also loops my button function in time with framerate. What I want is for the button to turn on when pressed once and turn off when pressed again irrespective of how long the button is pressed. Here is the code.

```java
else if (circle4.pressed()) {
  println("button 4 is pressed");

  if(drawCirclesPrimary){
  drawCirclesPrimary = false;
  }
  else{
  drawCirclesPrimary = true;
  }
  println("drawCirclesPrimary"+drawCirclesPrimary);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at the [Buttons tutorial](http://processing.org/learning/topics/buttons.html) on processing.org. The following code is a subset of what is contained in the tutorial (you will need to review all the code in the tutorial, however). Comments are mine.

```
void setup() { 
  // Create instances of your button(s)
}

void draw() { 
  // Draw buttons, update cursor position, check if buttons have been clicked.
}

// Provides the overRect() method (among others).
class Button
{
    // If the cursor is placed within the footprint of the button, return true.
    boolean overRect(int x, int y, int width, int height) 
    {
      if (mouseX >= x && mouseX <= x+width && mouseY >= y && mouseY <= y+height) {
        return true;
      } 
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }
}


class RectButton extends Button
{  
   // Create a rectangle button with these size/color attributes.
   RectButton(int ix, int iy, int isize, color icolor, color ihighlight) 
   {
      x = ix;
      y = iy;
      size = isize;
      basecolor = icolor;
      highlightcolor = ihighlight;
      currentcolor = basecolor;
   }

   // Determines whether the cursor is over the button.
   boolean over() 
   {
      if( overRect(x, y, size, size) ) {
        over = true;
        return true;
      } 
      else {
        over = false;
        return false;
      }
   }

   // Draws the rectangle button into your sketch.
   void display() 
   {
      stroke(255);
      fill(currentcolor);
      rect(x, y, size, size);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://processing.org/discourse/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1117673736) has some example code for drawing an object only while a key is pressed. That's pretty similar to what you want.

Instead of `keyPressed` and `keyReleased`, you can use `mouseClicked`. which is called once after a mouse button has been pressed and then released. Use a boolean variable to store the on/off state. Inside of `mouseClicked`, toggle the value of that boolean variable.